# Twin Bris conundrum 

Tags: brit-milah, riddle, twins

Twin brothers are born from the same mother on the very same morning. Both are perfectly healthy. Yet, the proper day for one’s bris mila is 8 days later, while the proper day
for the other one’s bris mila is not until the 9th day. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Shabbos morning and one was born naturally and one one was born via a c-section. The one born naturally has his Bris the following Shabbos, the one born via c-section has his Bris on Sunday the 9th day.

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/634611/jewish/Can-a-circumcision-be-conducted-on-Shabbat.htm